# How to sort sublists within a list according to specific attribute in python

Tags: python, list, sorting

I have a list in python that looks like below

```
a=[['David','McConor','123000','900']
['Timothy','Gerrard','123001','901']]
```

I desire to sort the list above using the last entry of each sublist as the key. I have succesfully sorted the list `lexicographically` using the `a.sort()`
function. Now i want to sort the list and print each sublist such that the list with `'901'` comes first is my problem.

**What I tried**

```
##defining what mykey is where am stuck
mykey=
##the sort function has overloads for key
a.sort(key=mykey,reverse=True)
```

Thanks for your contribution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an alternative way

```
sorted(a, key = lambda x: (x[-1]), reverse=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

`key` expects a function, you can create a simple lambda function to check for the last item:

```
a.sort(key=lambda x: x[-1],reverse=True)
```

Comment: OKay trying it right away

Comment: this is ingenius, thanks

Comment: You're welcome.